# Unexpected sort in a spark dag

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I have written the below code I want to read from kafka and write parquet files partitioned by year, month, day and hour.
In the dag I see a sort operation (image below).
Is this sort operation going to sort within an executor or move data between executors?
I would not expect that the job should need to shuffle data between executors, because a single executor can read from kafka and write a standalone parquet file in the folder.

```
     private val year = date_format($"timestamp", "yyyy").alias("year")
     private val month = date_format($"timestamp", "MM").alias("month")
     private val day = date_format($"timestamp", "dd").alias("day")
     private val hour = date_format($"timestamp", "HH").alias("hour")
     val source =  spark.readStream
      .format("org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider")
      .load()
    // transformation
     .select(year, month, day, hour, $"key", $"value",
      $"topic", $"partition".alias("partition_int"), $"offset", $"timestamp".cast("long").alias("timestamp_ms"),
      $"timestampType".alias("timestamp_type"))
     .writeStream
     .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(1000 * 60 * 3))
     .foreachBatch((batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) => {
                batchDF
                   .write
                   .mode("append")
                   .partitionBy("year", "month", "day", "hour")
                   .parquet(tableRoot)
     }).option("checkpointLocation", checkpointLocation)
     .start().awaitTermination()
```

[image: DAG with sort operation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is simply a sort per Task. No shuffling ever by partitionBy.